# group by on a particular column and select even rows for each group based on another column value

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have 100 million rows and I need to select even rows for each group based on another column value which has values in even, Since there is 100 million records therefore using dplyr takes lot of time,

[image]
I want in this fashion ->
[image]

I need query similar to this way as it executes very fast  although the below query is to select records group by on loan_num_srvcr

where diff_in_date (another column) has quantile value greater than 85

```
library(data.table)
setDT(r) 
r[, Q85 := quantile(diff_in_date, .85), by=loan_num_srvcr][diff_in_date > Q85]
```

Comment: I am not understanding. When you say "select even rows", do you mean rows 2, 4, 6, 8, ...? When you say "for each group", what is the grouping column? When you say "based on another column value which has values in even and odd" what is the name of the other column? Is this even criteria in addition to the other one? Or are you giving more details on the even criteria?

Comment: It would make things very clear if you give some sample data, the desired result, and an explanation based on the sample data. Then you can reference column names instead of just "group" and "another column". And the sample input will give people something to test code on. Since speed matters, we should test on large data. So please share code to generate, say 10,000 rows of sample data.

Comment: added an example , I hope this helps @Gregor Thomas

Comment: Thanks for the picture. It clears up the the logic a bit. Seems like `loan_num_srvcr` doesn't matter, because an even value for `Days` will be even regardless of what group it's in. Since you say speed matters, we should test on large data. Please share code to generate, say 10,000 rows of sample data. Pictures of data can sometimes help explain a problem, but they are useless for demonstrating and testing code, especially when you are looking for a highly efficient solution.

Comment: Please add a reproducible example and better explanation of the task.

Answer (score 0):

for the first qn, you can do something like:

```
setDT(r)[Days %% 2L == 0L][order(loan_num_srcvr, Days)]
```

for the 2nd qn, maybe something like:

```
setorder(setDT(r), loan_num_srvcr, Days)
setDT(r)[, N := .N, loan_num_srvcr]
r[rowid(loan_num_srvcr) / N > 0.85]
```